How to connect light fixture
So I was distracted while installing my new light fixture, and can't remeber how it was setup. I connected white to white, and I I'm not sure what to do next. Thnaks for you help

You have an old style switch loop(white connected to black) with new style switch cable.  Picture of how the switch is wired will help

I tries acessing switch, but I can't remove the screws. It's an old appartment and the screws are covered with a thick coat of paint. I only removed one wire nut, so I'm confused about how the old fixture was connected

I only removed two wire nuts (the one I reconnected in the picture, and another).

It is the two reds that are making it confusing.  Reds and blacks are for hot wires, The two reds also seem to be unneeded/unused for that light, unless a second switch also controls it.  It is also quite possible you should not be touching it in an apartment, only a license electrician.

And now you know that you should always take several clear pictures of the wiring connections BEFORE you unhook anything. Learn that lesson, at least.

Yeah, I know, Lessor learned. :-) But can you still help me?

Crip659, Yes! I do think a second switch can control it.

Now we are dealing with three way switches which makes life more confusing.  Most locations only allow you(if lucky) to do this in your own single family detached home that you own(not rent), multi-family buildings this is a big no-no.  You should get a licensed electrician to do this work, might need your landlord to call.

Can you please explain why this setup is complicated7 I posted a similar question about a year ago and got a quick anwer, and everything was fine. My landlord won't help because It's my responsability to change fixture. I don't care at all about the second switch. I just need to conect to fixture to the switch.

Nerver mind, I did it myself. Turns out it wasn't complicated at all. Cheers.
